# NIfi Controller Service One to One wth Processor, still needed?

Tags: apache-nifi, hortonworks-data-platform, hortonworks-dataflow

We have a `nifi` controller and processor pair that are one-to-one with the controller maintaining a connection factory to a specific JMS that can't be shared by another processor.

Is it advisable to git rid of the controller and create the connection factory in the processor for this case?  The controller has very little logic so I am considering consolidating.

Comment: Can you provide an example of code? If it is not related to coding/programming, maybe you have to post this in a different channel than stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

In general, Controller Services are meant for reuse across instances of a processor, and for multiple processors (such as an SSLContext which can be used for most/all HTTP-related processors).

If you know you'll only have a single processor, you can consolidate the controller service into the processor code. If you may have more than one processor (a GET and PUT, for example), then it's usually better to "future-proof" it and keep the Controller Service.